# C read lines of file to array prints only first character from line

Tags: c

I try to read the lines from an txt file to an array in C. By method to load the lines looks like this:

```
char *loadNames(FILE *file) {
    char *list = malloc(42);
    int BUFFER_SIZE = {256};
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char count;

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        list[count] = *buffer;
        count++;
    }

    return list;
}
```

At a later point in my code I call the function and print all values.

```
char *names = loadNames(file);
for (int i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
  printf("%c\n", names[i]);
}
```

The file contains a name in each line. The problem is that the current code only prints the first character of each name.

```
A
B
C
```

instead of

```
Anna
Berry
Chanel
```

If I print the value of `buffer` in the while statement from snippet #1 the full names are displayed.

What can I do to get the full names instead of only the first letters in my array?

Comment: That's expected, you only store the first character of each line. `list[count] = *buffer` copies exactly one character. There is no real string type in C.

Comment: Okay, so the buffer contains only on character and I need to add some logic to collect all characters until a linebreak and then write it to the array. Right?

Comment: Not quite.... Writing an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if 0    // uncomment this if strdup is not available on your platform
// Duplicate a string (google strdup for more information)
char **strdup(const char *source)
{
  char* newstring = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);
  if (newstring)
    strcpy(newstring, source);

  return newstring;
}
#endif


char **loadNames(FILE* file) {
  char **list = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 42); // you want 42 pointers to char, not 42 chars
  const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;        // just 256, not {256}
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];           // no need to allocate dynamically here
  char count = 0;                     // you forgot to initialize to 0

  while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
    list[count] = strdup(buffer);      // you need to duplicate the string,
                                      // not just assign a char
    count++;
  }

  return list;
}
```

There are still a problem with this code:

- if there are more than 42 lines in the file, you're in trouble.
- `loadnames` returns a pointer to an array of pointers, each of which point to a line of the file. The problem is once you've called `loadNames` you don't know how many lines have actually been read.
- there is no error checking whatsoever for brevity.

Comment: Surely the `while` condition should be `while (count < 4 && fgets(...)  != NULL)`

Comment: @EdHeal sure but it's `count < 42` not  `count < 4`. Anyway I edited and mentioned this problem

Comment: `char **list = malloc(42); ` -> `char **list = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 42);`

Comment: That works for me well. I had to change `strdup(list[count], buffer);` into `list[count] = strdup(buffer);`. I think thats because I'm on macos. Thank you very much. Also for pointing out what problem this code has.

Comment: You also need to add NULL at the end of the list

Comment: @Markus No, it's not because of macros, it's because the code in my answer was wrong. Your the correction you made is fine.

Comment: @EdHeal I mentioned this in the problems section

Comment: @Markus also have a look at the other answer, which addresses the second remaining problem

Comment: @Jabberwocky Alright. I'll do. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2):

C language has no true notion of strings. But the standard library defines strings as *null terminated char arrays* where `char` is the single character type. So what you want is closer to:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

char *loadNames(FILE *file) {
    char **list = malloc(42 * sizeof(char *));      // array of pointers
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char count = 0;                // never forget initialization

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        list[count] = strdup(buffer);          // allocate a new buffer
        count++;
    }
    list[count] = NULL;                        // sentinel value

    return list;
}
```

At the end, you should free all the allocated arrays:

```
for(i=0; i<42; i++) {
    if (list[i] == NULL) break;         // stop at the sentinel
    free(list[i]);
}
free(list);
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks good and is working well with one litte mistake. The first n names are some undefined characters like `@[���`. The curious thing is thats only the case for the first 7 lines after that its working well. Im sure thats no encoding mistake, because I put the last lines from the file to the start and the same behavior occurs. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Markus: I forgot to change the element size in the `malloc`. It could invoke Undefined Behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above that fixes your implementation of `loadNames`

You need

```
char **loadNames(FILE *file) {
  // See the other answers
}
```

Then

```
char **names = loadNames(file);

for(i=0; list[i] != NULL; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", names[i]);
}
```